# Is there any way to automate style creation

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I need many styles in my application which looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource RotondaTextBlock}" x:Key="HubItemName">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource KBlue}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 25 0 0"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource RotondaTextBlock}" x:Key="HubItemDesc">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource KOrange}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 15 0 0"/>
</Style>
```

I am just wondering if there is any way to create template for style and creae instance of styles something like:

```
<Style Template="MyTemplate" Foregraund="{StaticResource KOrange}" 
     FontSize="48" Margin="0 0 0 0" x:Key="NewStyle"/>
```